# Regex cutting the word in python

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize, data-preprocessing

```
import PyPDF2

fileReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file)
s=""
for i in range(2, fileReader.numPages):
    s+=fileReader.getPage(i).extractText()

from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')



sentences = []
while s.find('.') != -1:
    index = s.find('.')
    sentences.append(s[:index])
    s = s[index+1:]

#splits the text into array of sentences based on where we see a '.' - need to account for how to avoid breaking at e.g. Mr.



corpus=[]
for sentence in sentences:
    corpus.append(tokenizer.tokenize(sentence))
print(corpus[20])
```

The above is code for reading files and tokenizing the string. The output I get is as follows:

[image: Output]

But the desired output is:

```
['With', 'the', 'graph', 'of', 'COVID', '19', 'at', 'this', 'moment', 'have', 'started', 'a', 'slide', 'downward', 'trend', 'we', 'are', 'confident', 'of', 'all', 'our', 'brands', 'performing', 'strongly', 'in', 'the', 'coming', 'quarters']
```

i.e. the words should not get broken down. Is there any way to avoid this?

The string 's' is taken from a pdf and looks something like this:
[image: pdf text]

Comment: You haven't shown us what is in ` s`. That would probably explain *coming quarters*. Extracting text from a PDF isn't perfect, because of the layout-oriented nature of the PDF format. And you might consider using a sentence tokenizer to help avoid the *Mr.* issue.

Comment: @BoarGules i have edited the post to add the text. is there any other way to extract text if the source is a PDF?

Comment: In general, PDF isn't designed to have text extracted from it.

Comment: One possibility for this problem might be that there's some unprintable (whitespace) character between 'w' and 'e' that is not rendered in your PDF reader. If that's the case then the RE will *see* two separate tokens Also, consider using PyPDF4